# How to use last:child?

Tags: sass

I'm working with sass, and my code doesn't work.

I would like to take off the last ":after" (pipe) but I can't.

Thank You

```
.l-footer-top {
  .nav {
      a {
        color: $green;
        padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;

        &:after {
          content: '\00007C';
          color: theme-color('primary');
        }

        &:last-child:after a {
          content: none;
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good explanation of the problem

Comment: yes sorry, it's my first question :p my code gives nothing with my last-child.

Comment: Hi Cecile, could you please add also your HTML?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Code does not "give" anything

Comment: difficult for me to find : i have just a lit bit twig          <section class="l-footer-top py-1 bg-white">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              {{ page.footer_top }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

Comment: i would like to have  "contact | declaration | mention " and i have "contact | declaration | mention | " . i would like to delete the last pipe

Comment: it's something like this when i'm looking the console : <ul class="nav-item"><li class="nav-item"><a href="dsdsds">contact </a> </li> </ul>

Comment: Hi, you should accept the answer so that others can more easily find it ! Have a look at [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.l-footer-top {
  .nav-item {
    a {
      color: $green;
      padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      &::after {
        content: '\00007C';
        color: theme-color('primary');
      }
    }

    &:last-child a::after{
      content:none
    }
  }
}
```

Your `last-child` is a `<li>` not an `<a>`